# Changing font size using keyboard and mouse

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change font size by pressing certain things.
For example:

1. 'Alt' and '+'
2. Esc

Im having problems when it comes to Esc button. I know Esc button keyCode is 27 but it seems it's not working. I even try to use onkeyup but that didn't help either. Basically when i press Esc button it should return text to starting position which is 30pt. I'd appreciate any answer to how i can solve this problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>p{font-size: 30pt;}</style>
</head>
<body onmousedown="changeSize(event)" onkeyup="changeSize(event)">
     <p>Text1</p>
     <p>Text2</p>
     <p>Text3</p>
</body>

<script>
    var start = 30;
    var min = 10;
    var max = 50;
    function changeSize(e) {
    var b = e.keyCode;
    var c = e.button; 
    var fontSized = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    if (e.altKey){
            if (b == 107){
                if (start <=max && start >=min){
                start += 5;
                    for (i=0; i<=fontSized.length; i++){
                        fontSized[i].style.fontSize = start + "pt";
                    };  
                } 
            }
        }
    if (b == 27){
        start = 30;
        for (i=0; i<=fontSized.length; i++){
            fontSized[i].style.fontSize = start + "pt";
        };  
    }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser ? It does work for me on FF & chrome

Comment: @Kaiido I used different browsers (IE,Firefox,Chrome) but it didn't work in any of them. Although KoreanwGlasses code was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if (b == 27) {` is inside the `if (e.altKey) {` block so it will only work if alt is also pressed. 
Your code should look like this:

```
if (e.altKey){
    if (b == 107){
        if (start <=max && start >=min){
            start += 5;
            for (i=0; i<=fontSized.length; i++){
                fontSized[i].style.fontSize = start + "pt";
            };  
        } 
    }
}
if (b == 27){
    start = 30; // start == 30 is a comparator, and does not set start to 30
    for (i=0; i<=fontSized.length; i++){
        fontSized[i].style.fontSize = start + "pt";
    };  
}
```

Note that `start == 30` after `if (b == 27)` has been changed to `start = 30`

**EDIT:** After trying out your code, everything seems to work correctly, but to increase the font size you have to do Alt + '+' (on the Numeric Keypad!). You might want to consider doing Alt + Shift + '=' or just Alt + '='

For reference, here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>p{font-size: 30pt;}</style>
</head>
<body onmousedown="changeSize(event)" onkeyup="changeSize(event)">
     <p>Text1</p>
     <p>Text2</p>
     <p>Text3</p>
</body>

<script>
    var start = 30;
    var min = 10;
    var max = 50;
    function changeSize(e) {
    var b = e.keyCode;
    var c = e.button; 
    var fontSized = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    if (e.altKey) {
        if (b == 187){ // Now the combination is Alt + '='
            if (start <=max && start >=min){
                start += 5;
                    for (i=0; i<=fontSized.length; i++){
                        fontSized[i].style.fontSize = start + "pt";
                    };  
            } 
        }
    }
    if (b == 27){
            start = 30;
            for (i=0; i<=fontSized.length; i++){
                fontSized[i].style.fontSize = start + "pt";
            };  
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I forgot to paste in updated code. I already fixed it but that didn't fix my problem. Esc button is still not working. Also thanks for pointing out issue with start. @Korean

Comment: Interesting. Now that i completely replaced my code with yours Esc button seems to be working although i don't see any changes in the code. In case of Alt + '='. I tried multiple value but none of them worked. I used this as a reference point for keyCodes: http://www.expandinghead.net/keycode.html

Comment: Javascript key codes are different from alt-key codes. Try this -> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Comment: Ok, i figured out why that key code wasn't working. I had to change my keyboard layout to US keyboard. @Korean

Comment: Not related to the first question, but maybe there is a way to not use the same code twice (i' m talking about that for loop). @Korean

Comment: Heres a pastebin with a new function and everything: http://pastebin.com/6qL2PmEk

Comment: Ok, thank you! I made almost identical function as you did, the only thing that wasn't the same was fontSized. You put it in a second function. In my case i left in changeSize function, hence my function wasn't working. I didn't think of the scope. Thanks again. @Korean

Answer (score 0):

Often in these cases you need to block the event propagation because it will walk through all the parents until it hits the browser.